# Renaming a percentage of values with ifelse function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Understandably, there are probably easier ways to do this but I am interested in how the ifelse() function works. Say, for example, that I want to create a mutated dataset that removes the bottom 5% and top 5% of values from a particular variable in an original dataset. How can I use the ifelse() function to accomplish this. I have this code that was unsuccessful.

```
newdataset <- olddataset %>%
mutate(new_variable = ifelse(old_variable <= 0.05, old_variable >= 0.95, NA, old_variable)
```

Comment: Do you mean `olddataset %>%
  mutate(new_variable = ifelse(old_variable <= 0.05 | old_variable >= 0.95, NA, old_variable)
` ?

Comment: Can you provide the dataset of `olddataset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not so intuitive for me at first, but you can apparently supply a vector for a value argument in ifelse. (You have be careful about the length of vectors used in test expression and values, though.)

First, simulate some data.

```
data <- data.frame(var = rnorm(20))
```

Then, find a set of quantiles you want. Then use ifelse afterwards.

```
q <- quantile(data$var, probs=c(0.05, 0.95))
ifelse(data$var <= q[[1]] | data$var >= q[[2]], NA, data$var)
```

If you insist on using mutate,

```
mutate(data, new_var = ifelse(var <= q[[1]] | var >= q[[2]], NA, var))
```